# Returning value from delete statement in TableAdapters

Tags: asp.net, strongly-typed-dataset, tableadapter

Good Afternoon,

Does any body know if we can return values from a delete statement when using it with the TableAdapters (types dataset).

The delete statement uses a stored procedure which returns value. Can I get this value in my asp.net page?

thank you in advance.

Comment: If you like to use your name to sign messages, don't include it in the post, but change your username! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return the value if you define the query `ExecuteMode` as `Scalar` and then retrieve the value when you execute the query.

Here's a blog post showing how it's done in more detail: [How to retrieve stored procedure return values from TableAdapter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2006/08/09/693113.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WindowsApplication1.TasksDatasetTableAdapters {

public partial class tbTasksTableAdapter

{

    public object GetReturnValue(int commandIndex)

    {

        return this.CommandCollection[commandIndex].Parameters[0].Value;

    }

}
```

}

TasksDatasetTableAdapters.tbTasksTableAdapter taCustomers = new WindowsApplication1.TasksDatasetTableAdapters.tbTasksTableAdapter();

```
String taskName;

int taskPriority;

DateTime taskDueDate;

int returnValue;



taskName = "Test";

taskPriority = 1;

taskDueDate = System.DateTime.Now;



taCustomers.InsertTask(taskName, taskPriority, taskDueDate);

returnValue = (int)taCustomers.GetReturnValue(1);
```